# How to add header to selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

I have followed the instruction in the thread [Headers and Selenium Webdriver 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047195/headers-and-selenium-webdriver-2) but got the below error, is anyone awared of this issue?

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: : Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.

Comment: There is a way for Chrome using this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj which can be operated by Selenium on URL chrome-extension://idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj/popup.html